# Mainframe security

Tags: hardening

I am new to mainframe security testing practice. So far I have read a few articles on that even security of mainframe can be compromised.

I would like to know if there are any such checklists that the security tester follow while testing a mainframe application.

Comment: I have fixed your tags, as they are entirely off topic for this question.

Answer (score 7):

Anything **can** be compromised, however traditional mainframe configurations are very well structured so generally it is considered much harder than, for example, an average server running PHP:-)

Start with one of the security hardening guides for your mainframe. If you are running IBM, the manuals on IBM mainframe security will give you 95% of what you need.Start with the [redbooks.](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246776.pdf) The one I have linked to is over 500 pages and it is just one of many!

That said - if you are new to mainframe security, you really shouldn't be going anywhere near a mainframe. Generally they run high value data and tools...

Answer (score 7):

I think you'll have *fun* getting to grips with Mainframe security, it's quite a different world.

As @roryalsop says be very careful before you test a live mainframe, they tend to run very high value apps and can be fragile (i.e. if you break it, the test will likely end pretty quickly)

Some resources I would recommend

- [mainframes for security people](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mainframe-Basics-Security-Professionals-Getting-ebook/dp/B0013HZMPM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1395224910&sr=8-2&keywords=mainframe%20security)
- [Millenial Mainframer](http://www.millennialmainframer.com/)
- [Soldier of Fortran](http://mainframed767.tumblr.com/)
- [Mainframes for newbs](http://bigironnewb.blogspot.co.uk/)